# Return picker view to the previously selected row

Tags: swift

In my app I allow the user to change the colour theme for the app via a picker view. In doing this, UI elements such as the bars and buttons are changed based on what the user chooses.

I am having an issue with the picker view returning to the first item when the view is closed and reopened. How can I make the picker view return to the colour that the user previously selected?

Here is the code that I currently have for the picker view:

```
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return coloursArray.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return coloursArray[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent: Int) {
    colourSelected = row
    if colourSelected == 0 {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()
        changeButton.layer.backgroundColor = (UIColor.newBlueColor()).CGColor
    } else if colourSelected == 1 {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newGreenColor()
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newGreenColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.newGreenColor()
        UIButton.appearance().setTitleColor(UIColor.newGreenColor(), forState: UIControlState())
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newGreenColor()
        changeButton.layer.backgroundColor = (UIColor.newGreenColor()).CGColor
    } else if colourSelected == 2 {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newOrangeColor()
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newOrangeColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.newOrangeColor()
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newOrangeColor()
        changeButton.layer.backgroundColor = (UIColor.newOrangeColor()).CGColor
    } else if colourSelected == 3 {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newPurpleColor()
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newPurpleColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.newPurpleColor()
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newPurpleColor()
        changeButton.layer.backgroundColor = (UIColor.newPurpleColor()).CGColor
    } else if colourSelected == 4 {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newRedColor()
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newRedColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.newRedColor()
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newRedColor()
        changeButton.layer.backgroundColor = (UIColor.newRedColor()).CGColor
    } else if colourSelected == 5 {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.newTurquoiseColor()
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newTurquoiseColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.newTurquoiseColor()
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newTurquoiseColor()
        changeButton.layer.backgroundColor = (UIColor.newTurquoiseColor()).CGColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have one column ("component") in your picker:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let idx = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("SavedIndex")
   pickerView.selectRow(idx, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}
```

And, of course, save to `NSUserDefaults` when a row has been selected.

Depending on your setup, you might have to put this into `viewWillAppear()`.